# How to map a denormalised many to many relation(logically) in database in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many

I have a table called `person` which stores the details of a person in the application. To map to my application, I have a class called `Person` with the corresponding set of properties mapping to columns of the table.

One of the attributes of a person is the hobbies of that person, which can be multiple. I have also a master table for hobbies called `hobby`.

Naturally it's a many-to-many relationship which should be modelled by using a third table, something like *person_hobby*. But my application use case only requires listing down the hobbies of a person on kind of his/her profile page. So instead of making a third table, I have put a comma separated string of hobbies which I can split up in the application and iterate over to show it on the page.

But I want in my pojo `Person` it should be modelled as a `List<String>` rather than a single String with comma separated values and have the getter and setter accordingly.

How should I go about mapping it in the right way.

One thing that I thought of was creating another property `hobbiesStr` in the `Person` class and map it to the column `hobbies` and duplicate setters and getters for a `List<String>`, so that the getter of List would manipulate the csv of string and create a list on the fly. But then how do I cope with hibernate using setter for the string and getter for the list?

Comment: The simple answer is: don't denormalize like this. It's awful. You'll never be able to find people having a given hobby. Use a good old, standard, many-to-many association.

Comment: Can you paste the Person class you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can map a comma separated list with the code below. I doubt you can map it also with your `hobbies` table. I mean you are not going to have a foreign key or anything that can automatically check if all the items in the list have an appropriate record in the hobbies table. Also if you create a record for a person and provide some hobbies from your `hobbies` table after saving the person record, nothing will prevent from removing all the records from your `hobbies` table even if you have a person who has those hobbies in his/her list.

```
    private String hobbies;

    public List<String> getHobbies() {
        if (null == hobbies) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] hobbiesArray = hobbies.split(",");
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(hobbiesArray.length);
        for(String hobby: hobbiesArray) {
           result.add(hobby);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void setHobbies(List<String> hobbies) {
        if (null == hobbies) {
            return;
        }
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<String> iterator = hobbies.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            stringBuilder.append(iterator.next());
            if(!iterator.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }
            stringBuilder.append(",");
        }
        this.hobbies = stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Taking into consideration all the mess this approach can bring, I would think twice before I decide to go this way